# Advice needed to use Spark SQL engine to parse SQL for a custom library

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing a library in Scala to process data locally. I would like to include some of the functionalities that are available in Spark SQL. For example, I would like to be able to do something like:

```scala
val dataFrame: MyDataFrame

val filteredDataFrame = dataFrame.filter("field = 'value'")
```

And I want it to behave the same way it does in Spark. Since Spark supports SQL expressions there, I am assuming I need a SQL parser/engine to be able to achieve this. But at the same time, I do not want to implement it myself from scratch because that will most likely lead to important differences in the behaviour.

Could you give me some advice on how to reuse Spark SQL parser/engine so that most of the behaviour is the same? Which libraries should I use? Which parts will I be able to reuse and which ones do I have to implement myself?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Process data locally?. Do you want to process local files?

Comment: Why you do not simply use **Spark** in _local_ mode?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez that would imply loading a spark context and a sql context, which is costly and it is not compatible with what I am trying to achieve in the library.

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 yes, local files. But also locally, meaning not using a cluster or a distributed environment.

Comment: @Selnay so basically you want to write something like **Python** _Pandas_ in **Scala**? I had to admit that is a noble effort, but probably you will need to implement a lot of things. Good luck.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in your library? Because it seems like you're going to be rewriting Spark. Maybe you can look into Apache Calcite which provides a SQL parser.

Comment: You can use Spark csv plugin https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv. Your files can be text files with a csv-based format.